# Html Agility Pack can't remove node

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have just installed the Html Agility Pack to my asp.net project, I can use it to pull data from another web page on the web and display it without a problem, however I have hit a problem. Basically I have selected a div with the id of header, in this header I know there is a div with the class name login which I want to remove. So here is my code

```
    //Get the div with the id of footer
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='header']");

    //Remove login div
    HtmlNode loginSection = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='login']");

    node.RemoveChild(loginSection);
```

Now at the point I set the loginSection it has a value so I have selected a div that exists, but when I call the RemoveChild function I get this error

```
Node "<div class="login"></div>" was not found in the collection
```

I have looked at other questions on stackoverflow about this and I can't seem to find a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I need to select the parent node first to then select my loginSection node,

here is my updated and working code

```
    //Get the div with the id of footer
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='header']");

    //Remove login div
    HtmlNode loginSection = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='login']");

    loginSection.ParentNode.RemoveChild(loginSection);
```

Comment: I was just about to say is it really the child, but that would explain it.